# Achieving 25K Concurrent connections in RubyOnRails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I am trying to build a suggestion board application. where a users raises a query and multiple people will post at the same time. expected to be supporting atleast 25k concurrent users. now the question format also has checkboxes or radio buttons, in thats case they will be writing to DB.

Please let me know how can achieve this in Ruby on Rails.
- hardware support (specific Hardware LB)
- software support like (DB clustering/App server clustering/ Web traffic resolution)

Comment: This probably should be on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ since it isn't really a Rails or Ruby question, but instead is hardware and infrastructure.

Comment: Good luck with 25k *concurrent* connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best plan is to worry about scaling to this level once you have that many users. There's nothing stopping you from achieving this in Rails, or indeed any other framework/language.

The problem with trying to design your architecture up-front to scale to this level is that, at this point, you have absolutely no idea where the pain points are going to be. Are there specific pages which are going to hit the database harder, are some of your pages heavy on HTML and images... there are so many questions to ask that simply cannot be answered effectively until you've gotten something out there.

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't worry about scaling - by all means, try to design your data structures in such a way as to allow you to scale later. But put off any major decisions, and think about them later when you have some hard data to work with.

Comment: Thanks stephen, for your answer. I completely believe your suggestion is correct but currently I am trying to understand and decide on hardware and other load balancing options that needs to be implemented. I want the app to run seamlessly and so the client must have fair idea of costing & hardware infrastructure required if any. I would love if you can point me some architecture or ecosystem planning tools or suggestions which will be handy for me to suggest a appropriate solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't be any more helpful; this sort of thing doesn't generally fall inside my area of expertise. As @the Tin Man commented above, perhaps you'd be better trying serverfault.com for help?